# parse json string with forward slashes - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsonparser

Looks pretty simple but I am unable to figure it out

```
var str="[{name:\"House\",id:\"1\"},{name:\"House and Land\",id:\"5\"},{name:\"Land\",id:\"6\"},{name:\"Terrace\",id:\"11\"}]";
JSON.parse(str.replace(/\s/g, "").replace(/\//g, ''));
```

I am unable to the convert above string(which comes from 3rd party website) to valid json so that I can iterate it on my side

error

```
VM5304:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Are you sure the source string is not valid? It looks like the result of a JSON encoded value being included in another JSON encoded value.

Comment: JSON requires the index or key to be quoted

Comment: That's not a valid JSON, but it's ok for `console.log( eval( str ) )`

Comment: I'm with @Marty - this appears very familiar to valid JSON that is being displayed in debugging tools. Are you in actual possession of a string with slashes (i.e. you use it like `var string = ...` exactly as you have posted?), or is it being returned from some sort of ajax/api call and the slashes appear in your developer tools?

Comment: Ok, I've got it - somebody has `JSON.stringify`-ied an already valid JSON string (which adds the forward slashes) and now you are trying to parse it - that's what is really going on here.

Comment: Nope, I take it back - because the keys are unquoted (as pointed out in the accepted answer) somebody has obviously tried to a build a JSON string **by hand**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON requires the keys to be quoted. It appears that your keys are coming in unquoted. So add another `.replace` statement to insert the quote back in:

```
.replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

> Property names must be double-quoted strings; trailing commas are forbidden.

**COMPLETE SOLUTION:**

```
.replace(/(,|{)\s*(\w+)\s*:/g, '$1"$2":');
```